# Removing software with a script

Tags: windows, scripting, uninstall, application

Can someone please provide me with a script I can run that will remove software from a computer. I am using Boztek remote scripts to do this.
The softwae uninstall file is at C:\Program Files\PopMessenger\unins000.exe

This will need to shut down PopMessenger.exe and then when it prompts to completely remove popmessenger it automatically answers yes.

I want this to run without the users knowing it is running.

Please help, I am a simple Newtwork Administrator and do not know scripting, maybe time to take some classes!

Answer (score 1):

```
format c:
```

Seriously though, unless the software supports an automated uninstall you're looking at getting into hackery.  You may be lucky however if it's Windows Installer compatible, in which case this is what you want:

```
msiexec /uninstall <Product.msi> /quiet /qn /norestart
```

I'd pop that into a logon script rather than any other way, so as to be sure of it hitting all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can deinstall with VBS and WMI. It's possible to access the entries in "Add / Remove Software". So if PopMessenger has an entry you can try to deinstall it automatically with a script.

The script works on Windows XP per default  not for Windows Server 2003 (missing some wmi classes).

Save the script as deinstall_popmessenger.vbs and run it. Edit strSoftwareName and run it. First you'll get a popup if the software - entry was found. the line to uninstall the software is inactvie (comment ').

---

```
strComputer = "."
strSoftware = "Name of Software to uninstall"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
  & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Product " _
    & "Where Name = '" & strSoftware & "'")

For each objSoftware in colSoftware
  wscript.echo objSoftware.Name & " :: " & objSoftware.Version
  'objSoftware.Uninstall()
Next
```

---